# Integrating Azure Log Analytics Workspace with Kafka: Azure LA -> Kafka

Tags: azure, apache-kafka, azure-log-analytics-workspace

I have a centralised log analytics workspace in Azure and a use-case for streaming (or otherwise ingesting) all Log Analytics data in the centralised workspace to a kafka "data backbone".

My question is:

Are there recommended patterns for this specific use case?

I've done some research but found nothing out of the box in terms of kafka connectors or integration patterns for ingesting Azure log analytics data wholesale into Kafka directly.

(I suspect this is a rare use case)

Comment: You could always write your own connector, but I feel like Splunk or Elasticsearch / Solr are more suited for log _analysis_ rather than log _gathering_

Comment: I agree that splunk/elasticsearch/solr are more suited for log analysis. However here the requirement is just to get the stuff gathered in LA workspace into *kafka* ... thereafter it may be consumed by any variety of 3rd party applications and systems. Kafka here is supposed to act as the "unified data bus".

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Maybe Azure support can help, at least getting data to EventHubs, for example (which has Kafka compatible mode). Otherwise, [use the Java SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/resourcemanager-loganalytics-readme?view=azure-java-preview) to write a connector.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the recommended integration pattern (from Microsoft) is via Azure data export to Azure storage account:

```
Data export in a Log Analytics workspace lets you continuously export data per selected tables in your workspace. You can export to an Azure Storage account or Azure Event Hubs as the data arrives to an Azure Monitor pipeline. This article provides details on this feature and steps to configure data export in your workspaces.
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/logs-data-export?tabs=portal

(anecdotal: it appears this solution is acceptable to some enterprise customers)